# Set one class IBOutlet referencing outlet for another class textfiled?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to set one class reference outlet for another class textfield.
My first class has an IBOutlet reference outlet like below:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *presentInView;
```

I would like to set this `presentInView` reference outlet for another class textfield.

As per drag and drop process I was able to give this reference outlet for another class `textfield`. See image below:

[image]

But how is it possible programmatically?

Comment: a) Why can't you do this in Xcode b) Don't declare it as `IBOutlet` in the second class and you can just treat it as a variable (`class2.presentInView = self.presentInView`)

Comment: how to add presentInView reference to my textfield

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want a text field to have a variable for a `UIView`?

Comment: yes,That's what i want

Comment: But surely the class represents the view controller that is currently being presented.  How does it make sense to reference a textfield in another view controller?  This sounds like you aren't using the MVC pattern properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I totally agree with trojanfoe comments above (+1) - you never want one view controller's view managed by another view controller.

However, I've seen cases, where you would want to set text on text field of one view controller based on some condition occurring in another view controller. If you fall in that category, then this is what you need to do:

1. Expose a `NSString` property in the header file of first view
   controller. You may also expose `UITextField` property instead but
   try to abstract UI components exposure unless otherwise necessary.
2. Hold a reference of first view controller object shown on screen in second view controller.
3. Set the property created in #1 on the object created in #2 and you are all set.

PS: You can also use delegation pattern around this which makes more sense here.